# How to call a class in a different module from a function, while passing an argument?

Tags: python, function, class, module, attributeerror

I'm trying to run a function in a file from a different module while passing an argument but I keep getting: AttributeError: module 'folder1.file1' has no attribute 'function1'

I think something is going wrong while importing the module. When I have the two functions in the same file, everything goes according to plan, but when they are separated in different files I get this error. Probably I'm mixing up importing classes with importing functions?

folder1/file1:

```
def function1(a):
    answer = a
    print(answer)
```

folder2/file2:

```
from folder1 import file1

func1 = file1.function1() 
def function2():
    a = 5
    func1(a)
```

Comment: What is the hierarchy of the folders? Are you sure it's all correct? For convenience I had folder1 as a subfolder in folder2 and it worked. I just had to correct this `func1 = file1.function1`.

Comment: The folders have an indirect parent folder. But there are multiple folders in between.